# Getting TypeError when trying to compile the mock file imported from the @chianlink/contracts

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, hardhat, chainlink

I am getting the type error when I try to compile my mock file

Here's my mock file content

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
```

and this is the error I am getting when I try to compile it

> @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol:7:38:
> TypeError: Interfaces cannot inherit. interface AggregatorV2V3Interface is AggregatorInterface, AggregatorV3Interface

[image: Error]

My chainlink version `"@chainlink/contracts": "^0.3.1"`
Version I defined in the hardhat config

```
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {version: "0.8.9"},
      {version: "0.6.0"},
    ]
  },
```

I think the error is coming from the @chainlink/contracts. Therefore I tried to reinstall the package but the error remains the same.

I also tried to change the version of the @chainlink/contracts.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I installed the latest version of @chainlink and also updated my compiler version.
And instead of importing from v6.0. I am importing from v8.0

Answer (score 0):

you may change the version from this  {version: "0.6.0"} to {version: "0.6.6"}:

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {version: "0.8.9"},
      {version: "0.6.6"},
    ]
  },
```

and make sure the pragma version of the mock file has caret(^)

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
```

it is for compatible with version updates as minor/patch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).